# Facebook App ID, Facebook Pages, Likeboxes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Perhaps you can help me here: To use the Facebook JS Api, you need an App ID. So I created an application, used the App ID for a likebox on my website. Now it seems that when people click on like, they like the app and not my website ... now does someone know what to do if you want a Likebox for the website, and not for the app?

Have I screwed up?  I don't think I can convert the app to a facebook page (a fb "page" ist the right way to go here, isn't it?), can I?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To like a website rather than a page, you need to use the  'Like' widget.
This has a little more info for you and will generate the iframe code to add to your site too:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Hope that helps!